# Interval List Intersections

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

Given two lists of closed intervals, each list of intervals is pairwise disjoint and in sorted order.

Return the intersection of these two interval lists.

(Formally, a closed interval [a, b] (with a <= b) denotes the set of real numbers x with a <= x <= b.  The intersection of two closed intervals is a set of real numbers that is either empty, or can be represented as a closed interval.  For example, the intersection of [1, 3] and [2, 4] is [2, 3].)

[click this for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TJK1.png)

Comment: This was asked in leetcode may 22nd to 28th challenge

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public int[][] intervalIntersection(int[][] A, int[][] B) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res =  
              new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 

    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<B.length;j++){
        ArrayList<Integer> intersection = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(B[j][0] >= A[i][0] && B[j][0] <= A[i][1]){
            intersection.add(B[j][0]);
            intersection.add(A[i][1] <= B[j][1] ? A[i][1] : B[j][1]);
        }
        else if(A[i][0] >= B[j][0] && A[i][0] <= B[j][1]){
                intersection.add(A[i][0]);
                intersection.add(A[i][1] <= B[j][1] ? A[i][1] : B[j][1]);
            }
            if(!intersection.isEmpty())
            res.add(intersection);
        }

    }

    return res.stream().map(u -> u.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);


}
```

}

Comment: Please import streams